# Disable fan management on Dell Poweredge SC1425

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, fan

I have Dell Poweredge SC1425 server that has a failed fan. This causes the server to increase the speed of the other fans to their maximum. The server is being used in a very cool place so I was wondering if I could disabling the monitoring for the failed fan so that the other fans run at their normal speed. There's no danger of the server getting too hot so I'm not worried about overheating.

Answer (score 2):

Ebay $9.99 inc delivery - http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Poweredge-SC1425-System-Cooling-Fan-F7007-San-Ace-40-9CR0412S520-/370593394365?pt=COMP_EN_Networking_Components&hash=item5649166ebd

Comment: You just beat me to it. Was about to post the same ;-)

Comment: Bought one on ebay and got the wrong one delivered, I was hoping it'd be simple to disable fan management until I got the correct fan. Shipping from the US to me takes at least a week if not longer.

Comment: I successfully managed to use the stuff on this page to change the thresholds on a 2900 I run in my garage. http://projects.nuschkys.net/2011/11/15/how-to-adjust-the-fan-thresholds-of-a-dell-poweredge/ Please note-if you do fry your BIOS don't hold me responsible. You will need to install some version of linux temporarily (I used centos), and there will be a little fiddling as the page mentions success with 2800 and 2900, and also you will need to alter the threhold yourself as the provided script changed my fan failure threshold to 750 rpm. Just to make things clear, DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK!

Comment: @RobinGill that link in your comment is broken but i believe it is now located at http://dell.ionsystems.uk/ - the readme there mentions the same link

Answer (score 1):

Not if you care about your warranty.  Leave it alone.

If you're doing it because the server is too noisy, then I'm afraid you shouldn't have put it in a noise-critical place.  Servers are noisy. Servers are cleverer than you. Don't screw about with them, and they won't hate you.

Comment: There is no warranty, it's not a production server, it's for personal use.

Comment: An SC1425 is just slightly older than God. I can't imagine the OP has warranty left on it.

Comment: @EvanAnderson I was amazed to see it still works, except for the fan. As I recall the SC1425 usually had the heatsink coming loose of the CPU due to crumbling cooling paste. Typically about 2 hours after the warranty expired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unplugging the fan, and then rebooting?  I'm not sure about Dell machines, but on other servers that share the same behavior, doing this tends to make them forget the missing fan instead of freaking out.  You may need to check the BIOS settings for a "detect fans on boot" option.

You should still replace the bad fan when you can.